# Simple way to keep track of a high score with corona sdk

Tags: variables, save, coronasdk

I have nearly finished my game (just graphics and this to do) but do not know how I can save high scores. I searched corona's apis but did not manage to find what I needed. I also downloaded this http://techority.com/2011/12/28/ego-easy-saving-and-loading-in-your-corona-apps/ but it kept saving the wrong high scores...

Any ideas on the best and simplest way to do this will be greatly appreciated,

thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: Ego saves the value you tell it to, there's no logic in the class to impact the values at all. Maybe you put the file name and the value in reverse order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following to save highscores attached to my game. It is not EXACTLY the solution you want but you should be able to modify this for your needs.

I declare a global variable called highscore that keeps track of all the scores. Since I have a level selection screen and highscore screen I have decided to declare these in my menu so I can have them loaded and available before navigating the game.

I can then get each individual highscore for each level by simply calling `Highscores[levelNumber]`. When I want to change the highscore I simply call `Highscores[1] = 500` and remember to call `saveHighscores()`

Put the following into your main

```
local highscoreHandler = require("highscoreHandler")

highscores = 
{   
0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}

highscores = loadHighscores()
```

And put this into a seperate file called highscoreHandler.lua

```
local json = require "json"

function loadHighscores()
    local base = system.pathForFile( "highscores.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local jsoncontents = ""
    local highscoresArray = {}
    local file = io.open( base, "r" )
      if file then
        local jsoncontents = file:read( "*a" )
        highscoresArray = json.decode(jsoncontents);
        io.close( file ) 
        return highscoresArray
        end
     return highscores
  end

function saveHighscores()
      local base = system.pathForFile( "highscores.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
      local file = io.open(base, "w")
      local jsoncontents = json.encode(highscores)
      file:write( jsoncontents )
    io.close( file )
  end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great! Can I use your code in my game (just checking for copyright)?

Comment: Yes all the code here is free to use.

Comment: Ok thanks :) However I just ran into a problem: whenever I start the game for the first time on a new device there is a bug. It says that highscores[1] is nil instead of 0. Any ideas why it is doing that?

Comment: Good notice! I edited the code to take care of this bug, notice that the previous `Highscore` global varable changed name to `highscore`.  And the return mechanism of loadHighscores was changed. Remember to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you, so it can help others.

Comment: Yes sorry I thought I had accepted the answer... I will upvote all answers as soon as my reputation reaches 15. I think it might have unaccepted the answer when you modified it. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi Frozire! I was just about to upload my app when I realized that the highscore was not being saved when I quit the app entirely by double clicking the home button... I think it has to do with the saveHighscore function, I am not sure I am doing it right. Could you please clarify how to save it the correct way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Call savehighscoress in system events. Add event listener and save in on suspend and close.

Comment: yeah thats what I did but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: So if I put this: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/system/type.html (the example) in my main.lua file and put saveHighscores() instead of print(...) it should work?

Comment: Yes, and then change the system event to suspend or exit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help Frozire! My app has been published on Google play and will soon arrive on the appstore :)  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kylesg.tenseconds