# Issues with saving high scores in lua

Tags: file-io, permissions, lua, coronasdk

```
function saveScore()
    local path = system.pathForFile("scoredata001.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local file = io.open(path, "w")

    if file then
        local score=get_score() --The get_score() returns the value of current score which is saved in 'score'.
        local newScore = compareScore()
        local contents = tostring( newScore )
        file:write( contents )
        io.close( file )
        return true
    else
        print("Error: could not write Score")
        return false
    end
end

function loadScore()
    local path = system.pathForFile("scoredata001.txt", system.DocumentsDirectory)

    local contents = ""
    local file = io.open( path, "r" )
        if file then
            local contents = file:read( "*a" )
            local score = tonumber(contents);
            io.close( file )
            return score
        end
    print("Could not read scores from scoredata.txt")
    return nil
end

function return_highScore()
    local highscore=loadScore()
        if highscore==nil then 
            highscore=0
        end
    return highscore
end

function compareScore()
    local highscore=return_highScore()
    if highscore then
        local currscore=get_score()
            if highscore==0 then
                return highscore
            elseif currscore>highscore then 
                return currscore
            end
    end
    return true
end

function disp_permScore()
    local display_score=return_highScore()
    text_display2= display.newText("GAME OVER!\n BEST: " ..display_score, 0, 0, "Helvetica", 80)
    text_display2.x = centerX
    text_display2.y = centerY
    text_display2.alpha=1 

function gameOver()
    mainScreen()
    saveScore()
    disp_permScore()
end
```

(This is with refernce to previous question [Permission issues in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659252/permission-issues-in-lua) )

Basically I'm trying to build a game in lua (This is my first ever game)
But, I'm unable to save highscore to file. If it gets saved, then I'm unable to retrieve them. (In short, I always some or the other error/problem in executing the code.

Please have a look at the code above. I want to display both high score and current score. Current score is being displayed perfect. This is something I tried yesterday night. But now, the high score is not being saved in file. (i.e. the best always displays 0) Also, the cmd says "unable to read scores form scoredata.txt) I'm unable to find where I went wrong.

Please help with this?
Please tell where do I go wrong? 
Also, if possible, provide (or edit) the correct code please?

Comment: +1 about indenting. As it is the code isn't even syntactically valid (there's an `end` missing somewhere near the end). Proper indenting would have made that obvious. It is also a matter of courtesy to the people who try to read and understand the code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem on this line

```
if highscore==0
then
return highscore
```

Meaning you check if the highscore is 0 and if it is then you return it instead of the actual higher score.

Also, I don't know if your code was just pasting error, but without indenting your code it becomes really hard to read. Try and look again I indentet it and now the error becomes really easy to spot.

Comment: Thank you so much for indenting the code. 
And when  I run the code, the corona simulator output says "Could not read scores from scoredata.txt" means this error flashes from loadScore() function. I added assert function, and the error flashed "Permission denied" . What to do?

Comment: This could be a number of problems. Have you checked the file if it is there? Else my best suggestion would be to change your code into using JSON. That way you can make a single varaible and use it like this: "highscores.currentScore" and "highscore.highestScore". Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810358/simple-way-to-keep-track-of-a-high-score-with-corona-sdk/24810753#24810753 - Also remember to accept the answers on question by clicking the little "v" or approve mark next to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Frozire for your time and effort on my code. I  managed to save high score successfully without JSON. Thank you for your help :)